# Querydsl does it prevent SQL injection

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I've searched around without answers, does querydsl prevent sql injection?

There is nothing talking about that in their doc... I guess so but can't be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, parameters and constants are rendered as JDBC parameters in prepared statements, so you're still guarded against SQL Injection. That is, if you stick to the core functionality of Querydsl. If you start extending Querydsl using custom functions or template expression, you may create expressions that allow for arbitrary snippets to be injected into the query.